# Freeze an amount in address until I unfreeze it

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I would like to send a specific amount to another address. That amount is on the account but is freeze/blocked so is not possible to use it until I unblock it based on a contract.

Is it possible to achieve this with solidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve this with solidity?

Yes

You can create a contract like this, the following is just to give an example

```
pragma solidity 0.4;

contract account {
  address blocker;
  address user;
  bool isBlocked;
  function account(address blockerAccount, address _user) {
    blocker=blockerAccount;
    user=_user;
    isBlocked=true;
  }
  modifier isUnblocked() {
    if(!isBlocked) {
        _;
    }
  }
  modifier isBlocker(address msgSender) {
    if(msgSender == blocker) {
        _;
    }
  }
  modifier isUser(address msgSender) {
    if(msgSender == user) {
        _;
    }
  }
  function unblock() isBlocker(msg.sender) {
    isBlocked=false;
  }
  function withdraw(address withdrawAddress, uint amount) isUser(msg.sender) isUnblocked() {
    withdrawAddress.transfer(amount);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem of this example is that the user can still transfer ethers with another app/contract. Even if my contract says is blocked.

Comment: Can I know how  because the only way to send money out of the contract is through withdraw function which will not be invoked unlesss the modifier isUnblocked allows it.

Comment: Well, this blocking is only valid for this contract. Is a virtual block. The amount can be used in other contracts that I don't have control.

Comment: If the money is transferred to this contract along with the initialization of contract, then user will not be able to withdraw, but he can see that the money is intended to the user but he cannot claim it unless unblocked

Comment: Did you mean you want to block ether in an Externally Owned Account

Comment: This contract does not block ethers, just flag if the account can transfer or not. But only for this contract, ethers are available in any other contract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59909/discussion-between-yellowflash-and-enzo).

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity 0.4;

contract LockBox {
    uint256 delaySeconds;
    uint256 unlockTime;
    address owner;

    function LockBox(uint256 _delay) {
        delaySeconds = _delay;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // accept a single deposit of a specific amount
    function () payable {
        if (this.balance != 0)
            throw;
        if (msg.value != 10000) // change amount for your use
            throw;
        unlockTime = now + delaySeconds;
    }

    // withdraw if delaySeconds have passed
    function withdraw() {
        if (now <= unlockTime)
            throw;
        if (msg.sender != owner)
            throw;
        owner.transfer(this.balance);
    }
}
```

Not great code. Should have a lot more protections, but I tried to keep it simple and to the question.